# Is there a way to encode data from Windows-1253 encoding to ISO-8859-1 in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, hex, iso-8859-1

By mistake I encoded hex data with Windows-1253 (Java eclipse option) but the data should be encoded with ISO-8859-1. Is there a way to re encode the data to get the right conversion?

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Java supports `Windows-1253` (mine does), then yes. You can check with [Charset.isSupported](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#isSupported(java.lang.String)).

Re-encoding:

```
void encode( File src, File tgt ) throws IOException  {
  if (Charset.isSupported("Windows-1253")) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(src), "Windows-1253"))) {
      try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(tgt), "ISO-8859-1"))) {
        String del = "";
        for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
          bw.write(del);
          bw.write(line);
          del = "\r\n";
        }

        bw.flush();
      }
    }
  } else {
    throw new IOException("Unsupported character encoding: Windows-1253");
  }
}
```

(Not tested.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I tried it but the source and the target appear to be identical...The data file is 512 integers. Each integer is produced by 3 bytes of hexadecimals... from the following formula: int r = (b3 & 0xFF) | ((b2 & 0xFF) << 8) | ((b1 & 0x0F) << 16); I dont have the hexadecimals but just the integers that were produced...

Comment: @javac31 How you "create" the data that is written to a file is completely irrelevant for the file encoding.

Comment: @javac31 Windows-1253 and ISO-8859-1 are *character* encodings that coincide (i.e. they use the same binary values) for most characters. Character encodings are used to encode text data as binary data (a file is just a long sequence of bits). If you use a character encoding to write integers to a file, this means that you first convert your numbers to text and then write the text to the file using said character encoding. Consequently, you need to read your file *as text* and then parse the text to numbers to get your original data back.

Comment: I am afraid I can not write a computer program to perform this procedure, probably because I have not understand it correctly. I am very sad for this.

Comment: @javac31 If you open your file in a *text* editor, what do you see? Can you edit your question to include a short piece of the data you see in the text editor? Can you also edit your question to include a piece of the data you get when reading your file and what you expected to get instead? It would probably also help if you included sample code that shows how you created your file in the first place.

Comment: When I open a file I get the following numbers for example:194
189
166
198
125
57
146
253
111
57
117
116
111
116
111
118
113
100
111
103
100 There are two negative peaks that there should not be there, with value of 57.

Comment: @javac31 What data did you expect instead of `57`?

Comment: I dont know exactly something like 150...

Comment: @javac31 Windows-1253 and ISO-8859-1 do not differ for the text `"57"`. You either wrote the wrong data to your file in the first place or your expectations about your data are incorrect. In either case, you cannot solve this problem through re-encoding.

Comment: When I use iso-8859-1 encoding to write the data files I dont get these unexpected peaks...

Comment: @javac31 Post the code you use for writing files with Windows-1253 encoding and the code used for ISO-8859-1. If you get different results for text that consists of numerals and blanks only, there has to be something very wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The way I read the data from java is this:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.